# How to apply function to multiple data frames

Tags: r, function, apply

I am trying to write a function that runs a rolling regression across multiple columns in a data frame using the `roll_lm` function in the package `roll`. I then want to apply this function to multiple data frames with the same formatting, but different x values. I am running a regression with x = RunTime and the remaining columns being the separate y values. RunTime values are different for each data frame. Below is what I have so far to run the desired function on the data frame Sum_9.18 of which I have many other similar data frames.

```
fun1 <- function(y) {
roll_lm(Sum_9.18$RunTime, y, width = 100)
}
test1 <- data.frame(lapply(Sum_9.18[2:11], fun1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give a solution that uses the `lm()` model, as I don't have the `roll` package installed.

First I will assume that you are able to store the data frames in a list. When this is the case, you can use `lapply()` to iterate on each data frame on which you want to apply your `fun1()` function.

So, conceptually, we would have two different functions called by `lapply()`, *one at the **outer level** that iterates on the **data frames***, and *one at the **inner level** that iterates on the **columns*** of the analyzed data frame. The inner function would be your `fun1()` function, but I will call it `fun_inner()` for increased clarity.

So, suppose you have a list of data frames called `list_of_dfs`, then the following functions would allow you to do what you need (you will just need to adapt the `fun_inner()` function to call the `roll_lm()` function):

```
#' Fits a predictive model using each column of a data frame as target variable
#'
#' @param df data frame with the data to fit.
#' @param target_columns name or index of the column(s) in data frame \code{df}
#' to be used as target variables, one at a time.
#' @param pred_columns name or index of the column(s) in data frame \code{df}
#' to be used as predictor variables.
#' @param fun_model function to be called that fits the model \code{y ~ X}
#' where \code{y} is each variable taken from the \code{target_columns} of the input data frame
#' and \code{X} is the set of predictor variables taken from the \code{pred_columns}
#' of the input data frame.
#' 
#' @return a list containing the result of the model fit to each target variable.
fun_outer_iterate_on_dfs <- function(df, target_columns, pred_columns, fun_model) {
  lapply(df[, target_columns, drop=FALSE], fun_model, as.matrix(df[, pred_columns, drop=FALSE]))
}

#' Fits an lm( y ~ X ) model. \code{y} is a numeric vector and \code{X} is a matrix.
fun_inner_fit_model <- function(y, X) {
  lm( y ~ X )
}
```

Here is an use case example:

```
set.seed(1717)
nobs = 10
# List containing the data frames to be used in the model fits
list_of_dfs[[1]] = data.frame(RunTime=rnorm(nobs), y1=rnorm(nobs), y2=rnorm(nobs))
list_of_dfs[[2]] = data.frame(RunTime=rnorm(nobs), y1=rnorm(nobs), y2=rnorm(nobs))
list_of_dfs[[3]] = data.frame(RunTime=rnorm(nobs), y1=rnorm(nobs), y2=rnorm(nobs))

test_models_on_each_df <- lapply(list_of_dfs, fun_outer_iterate_on_dfs, c("y1", "y2"),
"RunTime", fun_inner_fit_model)
```

Note how we can pass more arguments (other than the first) to the function called by `lapply()` by simply listing them after the function name (in this case after `fun_outer_iterate_on_dfs`).

The column names passed to the `fun_outer_iterate_on_dfs()` function can also be *column indices*.

The above code gives something like:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$y1

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
   -0.05994     -0.11727  

[[1]]$y2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
    0.02854     -0.08574  

[[2]]
[[2]]$y1

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
   -0.23479     -0.01973  

[[2]]$y2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
    0.07248     -0.33088  

[[3]]
[[3]]$y1

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
    -0.3087      -0.1191  

[[3]]$y2

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
     0.1765       0.5085
```

where we see that two regressions were fit to each of the three data frames, one on target variable `y1` and one on target variable `y2`.

---

Finally, if you already have the data frames stored as different objects, you can use the following **code snippet to store the data frames in a list**, which assumes that all data frame names follow the pattern `Sum_*` and that all objects with this pattern defined in the workspace are the data frames of interest:

```
#' Stores objects in the workspace whose name satisfies a given pattern in a list
#' 
#' @param pattern regular expression to be satisfied by the name of the object to store in the list.
#' @return a named list whose elements are the objects found in the parent environment satisfying the given pattern.
#' The name of each element is the name of the object.
store_objects_in_list <- function(pattern) {
  object_names = ls(pattern=pattern, envir=parent.frame())
  list_with_objects = lapply(object_names, get)
  names(list_with_objects) = object_names
  return(list_with_objects)
}
list_of_dfs <- store_objects_in_list("^Sum_")
```